# How do I delete displayed objects in python with pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make asteroids drop from the top straight to the bottom of the screen and then disappear.
To do this I have made multiple objects of class Asteroid, however I can't delete them afterwards.

```
A = []
while gameLoop:
...

a = Asteroid()
A.append(a)`

for i in A:
    i.move()
    if i.pos > dWidth:
         del i  # This doesn't remove the object
```

Is there any way to delete them?

Comment: Please show us the Asteroid class so we can decide how to delete these objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement a `delete` method in the `Asteroid` class, and call `i.delete()` in your `if` condition.

**How** to delete depends on **how** they are shown in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

In pygame your objects should usually be subclasses of [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and should be stored in [sprite groups](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) which allow you to update and render all contained sprites by calling the `update` and `draw` methods. You can remove the sprites from the corresponding groups by calling their `kill` method.

In this example I add `Projectile` sprites to the `all_sprites` group each frame and `kill` them if they are outside of the `game_area` rect. [`pygame.Rect`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) have a `contains` method that you can use to check if one rect is inside of another rect. Alternatively, you can just check if the rect's x or y attributes are less than 0 or greater than the screen's width and height.

```
import random

import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Projectile(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, game_area):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 5))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('aquamarine2'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(2, 0).rotate(random.randrange(360))
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        self.game_area = game_area

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if not self.game_area.contains(self.rect):
            self.kill()


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    game_area = pg.Rect(60, 60, 520, 360)
    game_area_color = pg.Color('aquamarine2')
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group(Projectile(game_area.center, game_area))

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        all_sprites.add(Projectile(game_area.center, game_area))
        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pg.draw.rect(screen, game_area_color, game_area, 2)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Here's a sprite and sprite group [tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13).