# Pygame - Shooting function with two players

Tags: python, pygame

I've been working on a game there two players [In this case just rects because its easy to draw and the sprite.collide_rect function returns a bool] that fight each-other. I've wanted to add a shooting function for the game but there was no real solution to create one in a two player game.

What I want to do is that when the first player presses space or the second player presses f, they both shoot their own type of bullet that does not collide with them but collides with their enemy and vice versa.

Is there a way to do this in pygame?
(Sorry if my explanation is not the best)

Here is some parts of the code that is relevant

```
    #Sprite Config
    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self, image):

            super().__init__()

             self.image = image
             self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        def right(self, pixels):
            self.rect.x += pixels

        def left (self, pixels):
            self.rect.x -= pixels

        def up(self, pixels):
            self.rect.y -= pixels

        def down(self, pixels):
            self.rect.y += pixels

        def dashleft(self, pixels):
            self.rect.x -= pixels

        def dashright(self, pixels):
            self.rect.x += pixels


    # Collision Logic

    collision = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Player1, Player2)

    if collision == True:
        AllSprites.remove(Player1, Player2)
        pygame.display.set_caption("They Destroyed Eachother! Space to retry")
        Player1.rect.x = BlueSpawnX
        Player1.rect.y = BlueSpawnY
        Player2.rect.x = OrangeSpawnX
        Player2.rect.y = OrangeSpawnY
        Again = True

    if Again == True and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        AllSprites.add(Player1, Player2)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Circles Fight!")

    AllSprites.update()

    # Drawing
    Screen.fill(Black)
    Screen.blit(Text,
               (250 - Text.get_width() // 2, 240 - Text.get_height() // 2))
    AllSprites.draw(Screen)

    # Closing
    pygame.display.flip()
    Clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You cant expect people to write your game for you. What code did you try to achieve what you want so far. Give us the specific part of code and not the whole game file.

Comment: I can also open a chat room if you need extended help, but read or watch some tuts first.

Comment: There are no tutorials, no videos, just random questions with no relation to what I'm doing. I examined the questions as hard as possible and theres still things that I dont know. How am I supposed to differentiate player ones bullets from the other? How am I supposed to make them move? What even is a game area?   I need help.

Comment: skrx? Are you still here?

Comment: I've taken the time to write an example program. I commented the important sections and the rest is hopefully self-explanatory. BTW, write @skrx to send me a notification.

Comment: Where is it? Also thanks! @skrx

Comment: @skrx Heres some more questions: Can I move the variables and functions out of the game class and instead place them into their own files and just run the functions in a game loop? If I cant do that ill adapt my code into your style and start from there.

Comment: That would probably work, too, the `Game` class is just a means of organizing the code in a better way.

Comment: cool, although it would be a pain, so im just going to refactor everything i have so far to the more convenient way, as i figured out that i could downside my amount of files from 4(var, function, sprite, main) into just two (config(contains game class and sprite classes), and main.

Comment: @skrx, never mind, it looks like we might need to set up a chat. Sorry, I'm just a very picky person with coding styles.

Comment: Here's the chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/158551/snivydroids-pygame-project?tab=general

Comment: got it, ill get to you when I get home and actually have free time @skrx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example in which I store references to the two bullet groups inside of the players. If you press the fire key ('f' or space) a bullet instance is added to the player's bullet group and the `all_sprites` group which blits and updates them.

The collision detection takes place in the `update` method where I check if the player collides with bullets of the `self.enemy_bullets` group. If there are collisions, I reduce the `self.health` and if it's `<= 0`, I call `self.kill()` to remove the sprite from all sprite groups.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, color, left, right, up, down, fire,
                 all_sprites, bullets, enemy_bullets):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2(self.rect.topleft)
        self.dt = 0.03
        self.key_left = left
        self.key_right = right
        self.key_up = up
        self.key_down = down
        self.key_fire = fire
        # Store the groups as attributes, so that you can add bullets
        # and use them for the collision detection in the update method.
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.bullets = bullets
        self.enemy_bullets = enemy_bullets
        self.fire_direction = Vector2(350, 0)
        self.health = 3

    def update(self, dt):
        self.dt = dt
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        # Check if enemy bullets collide with the player, reduce
        # health and kill self if health is <= 0.
        collided_bullets = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.enemy_bullets, True)
        for bullet in collided_bullets:
            self.health -= 1
            if self.health <= 0:
                self.kill()

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == self.key_left:
                self.vel.x = -90 * self.dt
                self.fire_direction = Vector2(-350, 0)
            elif event.key == self.key_right:
                self.vel.x = 90 * self.dt
                self.fire_direction = Vector2(350, 0)
            elif event.key == self.key_up:
                self.vel.y = -90 * self.dt
                self.fire_direction = Vector2(0, -350)
            elif event.key == self.key_down:
                self.vel.y = 90 * self.dt
                self.fire_direction = Vector2(0, 350)
            elif event.key == self.key_fire:  # Add a bullet to the groups.
                bullet = Bullet(self.rect.center, self.fire_direction)
                self.bullets.add(bullet)
                self.all_sprites.add(bullet)
        elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == self.key_left and self.vel.x < 0:
                self.vel.x = 0
            elif event.key == self.key_right and self.vel.x > 0:
                self.vel.x = 0
            elif event.key == self.key_up and self.vel.y < 0:
                self.vel.y = 0
            elif event.key == self.key_down and self.vel.y > 0:
                self.vel.y = 0


class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, velocity):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 5))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('aquamarine1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = velocity

    def update(self, dt):
        self.pos += self.vel * dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.fps = 30
        self.done = False
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.bg_color = pg.Color('gray30')

        # Sprite groups that contain the players and bullets.
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets1 = pg.sprite.Group()  # Will contain bullets of player1.
        self.bullets2 = pg.sprite.Group()  # Will contain bullets of player2.
        player1 = Player(
            (100, 300), pg.Color('dodgerblue2'),
            pg.K_a, pg.K_d, pg.K_w, pg.K_s, pg.K_f,
            self.all_sprites, self.bullets1, self.bullets2)  # Pass the groups.
        player2 = Player(
            (300, 400),  pg.Color('sienna2'),
            pg.K_j, pg.K_l, pg.K_i, pg.K_k, pg.K_SPACE,
            self.all_sprites, self.bullets2, self.bullets1)  # Pass the groups.
        self.all_sprites.add(player1, player2)
        self.players = pg.sprite.Group(player1, player2)

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(self.fps) / 1000
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic()
            self.draw()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            for player in self.players:
                player.handle_event(event)

    def run_logic(self):
        self.all_sprites.update(self.dt)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    Game().run()
    pg.quit()
```

---

If you rather want to do the event handling directly in the event loop, you can move the code in the `Player`'s `handle_event` method to the `Game`'s `handle_event` method. Here's a shortened example:

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('steelblue2'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos


class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, velocity):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 5))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('aquamarine1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = velocity

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((100, 300), all_sprites)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player.vel.x = 5
                elif event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    # Just create a bullet and add it to the sprite groups.
                    bullet = Bullet(player.rect.center, Vector2(8, 0))
                    bullets.add(bullet)
                    all_sprites.add(bullet)
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player.vel.x = 0

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: In the `Bullet.update` method you need to add code to remove the bullet when it leaves the screen.

Comment: No offense, but you have a **way** different coding method than me (ex:I dont use a game function to run most of it, everything is on either the main game file or in a variables/sprites/functions file) im going to try refactoring this but if I cannot get the hang of it maybe you can open a chat. Thanks anyway. @skrx

Comment: `dt` means [delta time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_time), the time that has passed since the last tick. You need it to make the movement speed of your sprites frame rate independent. The code stems from one of my templates and I just kept the `dt` in the example, but you can ignore it or remove it for the moment.

Comment: Regarding the 'key' attributes, if you don't store them in the players, you have to duplicate a lot of the event handling code in the event loop. The `handle_event` method can be moved to the event loop if you want, you just have to keep the `for player in self.players:` loop to avoid the duplication. I think it fits better in the `Player` class, because so many instance attributes are manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.
Just read the documentation for [sprite Groups on pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) documentation now.

Then, create another class inheriting from `pygame.spite.Sprite` for the bullets themselves, and whenever one player shoots, just create the new bullet, and add it to a "player1_shoots" Group. You can call collide methods on the groups, that will check for collisions on all sprites in that group, so, by using this Object oriented approach, you get multiple shots by player basically for free.

Also, note that you should code an "update" method on your bullet class that moves the bullet in the right direction. Then you just have to call `group.update()`  to have all bullets updated at once.

As a side note, try using different images than rectangles if you want - you will note that for the speed most games run, there is little difference if collision is calculated against the actual image or on a pixel by pixel games. You will need a very specific game to need more than rect-collision. And when you do, Pyagme even offers support for that.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I code into the update() function? and how do I make sure they dont fly off the screen and continue taxing the cpu?

Comment: I've answered the second question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035219/6220679

Comment: I tried my best to refactor that code into something that will work but the code ballooned into hot garbage, I'm going to refactor my code into seperate files and ill keep you updated to see if i can get it to work

Comment: you should havre velocity attributes on the bullet objetcs. say, "vx" and "vy". ach update, you add those to the bullet's rect x and y coordinates. Then you check, if they fall off the play area, just call "self.kill()" - they will be removed from the groups, and no longer updated. (and deleted from memory by Python if they are not in any other variable)

Comment: I still have no idea what to do. What do i put in an update function? How do I remove bullets on collision? How to a determine which bullets are which? What even is a game area? I have no idea.

Comment: @skrx alright, I tried to understand this but there is some things that don't make sense as I have not learned yet. What is self.dt? what is the point of mapping the keys as attributes? How do I turn the functions for running a game back into a game/event loop? (its easier for me). Do you have a discord or can you start a chat as I may need a little tutorial, thanks anyway